# Button error Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, button, firebase-realtime-database, onclick

I've written an application which should set a number of points for a user in a database - either 1 point or 3 points depending on which button is pressed.

However when I click the 1 point button it's OK but after that if I click the 3 point button, it firstly gives 1 point then when I click again it gives 3 points in my Firebase database.

The code is as follows:

```
public class AdminSetPoint extends Activity {
DatabaseReference dbref;
int point3 = 3;
int point1 = 1;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
String omer = "curUmar";String yusuf = "curYosof";String batu="curBatu";String hafta = "curHafta";
String perat="curPerat";String ogun = "curOgun";String emiran = "curEmiran";String said= "curSaid";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.admin_activity);
    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Skorlar", 0);
    editor=sharedPref.edit();

    editor.apply();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.umarbtn1:
            dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Umar").child("Point");
            dinle(dbref, point1,omer);
            int o1= sharedPref.getInt(omer,0);
            dbref.setValue(o1);
            break;
        case R.id.umarbtn3:
            dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Umar").child("Point");
            dinle(dbref, point3,omer);
            int o3= sharedPref.getInt(omer,0);
            dbref.setValue(o3);
            break;

 public void dinle(final DatabaseReference dbr, final int point, final String isim) {
    dbr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         String current_point=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
         int a= Integer.parseInt(current_point);
         editor.putInt(isim,a+point);
         editor.apply();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I hope I've edited your question accurately, and not changed any of the key parts that you were hoping to ask. I removed the screenshot of your code, as you included the actual code in your question, which is always better than an image. It's a bit hard to tell what the code is supposed to do from the names you've used for things (like `dinle` - I don't know what that means). You might find that editing those to be more self-documenting will help you get good answers.

Comment: Thank you for your advice bro . (meanwhile dinle turkish means to listen :) i write randomly but I will give a more meaningful name to next time bro )

Answer (score -1):

Change your onClick() to something like this . I have pasted this code to match your existing code as per my understanding in which i am supposing few things i.e you want to save new **o1/o3(value) +point** in pref and **o1/o3(value)** on firebase. if this is not the case, change it accordingly or explain what is **point** in your code .

```
public void onClick (View v){
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.umarbtn1:
                int o1 = sharedPref.getInt(omer, 0);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Umar").child("Point").setValue(o1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            editor.putInt(omer, o1 + point);
                            editor.apply();
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;
            case R.id.umarbtn3:
                int o3 = sharedPref.getInt(omer, 0);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Umar").child("Point").setValue(o3).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            editor.putInt(omer, o3 + point);
                            editor.apply();
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;


        }
    }
```

Comment: it didn't work bro . it didn't enter onComplete method

Comment: @Superpace.. verify the path for which you are settings up the value i.e o1 if it is valid or not.